# how to get text beside image button using CSS

Tags: html, css

I was trying to create a button using CSS. The html code looks like

```
<div class="content">
    <img src="http://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/socialmediaicons_v120/48/google.png"/ width="20" height="20">
    <span class="fon">Google</span>
</div>
```

And CSS is

```
.content {
    width: 120px;
    overflow: hidden;
   color: #f5f5f5;
  background: #2d3f51;
}

.content img {
    margin: 5px;
    float: left;
}

.fon{
  position:relative;top:5px;
}
```

I'm getting output as expected, but I wanted to reduce repetitive html code and move them to CSS, so that I just need to write code similar to below code and should show same output :

```
<span class="mybutton">Google</span>
```

Here is my JSFiddle

**http://jsfiddle.net/WW4N6/678/**

Comment: So you want to use css only to style span without adding any class? I'm I right?

Comment: Yes.. Correct.. But, if required we can have additional CSS class. But, needed in single html code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

html

```
<p class="mybutton">Google</p>
```

css

```
.mybutton {
  background: #2d3f51;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.mybutton:before {
  content: '';
  background: url('http://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/socialmediaicons_v120/48/google.png');
  background-size: cover;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WW4N6/681/

Comment: Exactly..!! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome. Note: use prefix when using flexbox. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp

Answer (score 1):

css

```css
.mybutton {
  width: 90px;
  height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  background: #2d3f51;
  background-image: url(http://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/socialmediaicons_v120/48/google.png);
  background-size: 20px, 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 5px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

jsFiddle link
http://jsfiddle.net/joshchurning/9sysby5f/

Answer (score 0):

you could use css's `background` property for your button:

```
.mybutton {
    ....
    background: url('http://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/socialmediaicons_v120/48/google.png') no-repeat center center #2d3f51
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of the HTML code (the width and length of img, I'm assuming), you could just put the width and height in your  `.content img` CSS class

```
.content img {
    margin: 5px;
    float: left;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
```